# Finding the Percentage of a Group of Items / Total Items

Tags: percentages

This may sound very stupid, but my brain stuck and I can't get it Right.

**What I have:**

1. `10 Categories` in which a number of Items (Item1, Item2, Item3) are stored.
2. In a Category there can be 0 or 100000 Items.

**What I want:**

Based on the item's in the Category, I want to find the `Percentage` every Category takes up.

These are the variables i have:

```
$category1_items    <- All items of an Individual Category
$all_items          <- All Items (#)
$all_categories     <- All Categories (#)
```

I need to calculate `$category1_percentage` (and of every other category) so that i can display the Percentage of each individual Category.

I can add any other variable i need.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: could you explicit what are your variables? (array,double,etc)

Comment: I don't understand. Every variable stores a number, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Then category1_items/all_items is what you look

Comment: But for the Percentage #(100%) i need a multiplier (*)... right ?

Comment: yes, for putting in a percentage you need to multiply by 100

Comment: so category1_items/all_items * 100 ?

Comment: yes that's all.

Comment: Thanks,you can Answer so i can upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$category1_items` / `$all_items`  $\cdot 100$